# Debugging JavaScript in client

Tags: javascript

I'm facing an issue while debugging my application. Following is the architecture:
Server: Java (Servlet)
Client: React+D3
Problem: Whenever, I change some react or d3 code and if an error occurs then it just shows me that some react (or d3) error has occurred but never tells me which function the error occurred (as seen in snapshot). Now, I know that simply debugging it by having the information like variable name and searching where I defined that variable. However, situation becomes tough when I use same object multiple times (say `window`) and had made several changes in the code. In this case, a specific line number where the error occured can be handy and quick. Let me know if I'm missing some basics about debugging such applications?[image]

EDIT1: 
1. In the snapshot, `http://localhost:8080/..../Server` Server is the main servlet application, kind of launchpad, which triggers several other react-based js files. 
2. The mentioned `ReferenceError` is inside a `function updateWindow()` but the console never mentions this (and that's my problem).

PS: I'm using Eclipse tomcat on server-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's no straight forward solution to this problem. So, I'll post the method that worked for me with few additional points:

- **Problem**: It doesn't gives a nice error trace like standard Java application, probably because it mixes with JavaScript code.
- At every line of the error trace, `line:column` specifies the error line. I used this as a reference and started manual debugging from where my application launches i.e. `Server.java` and look where I defined the `createChart()` in the JS file and drill-down until I found the referenced variable.
- In case of ReactJS' error (an error after resolving reference issue), I debugged it with normal `react.js` (not minified version `react.min.js`) so that it shows me exact line of error. Minified version is cluttered and is useless while debugging.

PS: If someone has better answer I'll edit this in future.